# The tightest bound on an integral

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

Consider a polynomial $p(x)$ where $p(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $p(0)=0$. Let $s(x)$ be an increasing analytic function such that $s(0)=0$ and $s(1)=1$. I am interested to bound the following integral:
$\int_{0}^1 p'(s(x))(s'(x))^2 dx$.

Note that I can rewrite the above integral to the form:
$\int_{0}^1 \frac{d p(s(x))}{dx} s'(x) dx$

Comment: Any $C^1$ function can be approximated by analytic functions (or even polynomials) in $C^1$ norm. So, all you really know about $s'$ is that it's a continuous function with integral $1$. The integral of $(s')^2$ can be as large as it pleases. So, even for $p(x)=x$ there is no bound for general $s$. You should try to specify what kind of terms do you want to see in the upper estimate.

Comment: Yes you are right. I must have added that $|s'|$ is bounded. For example,  if we knew $s'$, one possible bound would be $Max(s')p(1)$. I also know that $s'(0)=s'(1)=0$.